# How can I display the results, limiting the second table and view the time difference

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

My issue is that I have a SQL query

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.title
     , t.message
     , t.date
     , r.tid
     , r.admin
     , r.message
     , r.date 
  FROM tbltickets t
     , tblticketreplies r 
 WHERE t.id = r.tid 
   AND t.date BETWEEN '2017-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-14 00:00:00'
```

When this is run the output in phpMyAdmin is the following

[image]

As you can see I tie the tables by their id and tid, which works fine, but it's showing me to many results, it's showing me to many r.replies which is "Ticket Replies" when I only want to see the very first one.

I am aware I can do "GROUP BY t.date" and that limits it showing just

[image]

Which looks good, but here is my problem. you see the two timestamps one is t.date and the other is r.date.

What I want to do now is only filter the results where the r.date is more than 24 hours older than t.date which is the ticket date on the left, the problem with this is when I run something like DATE_ADD it will just jump to the "next r.message since i grouped it by t.date. It will just hide the message you are seeing in my screenshot #1 where it says "Hello, Thank you for contacting support" and will come out like this.

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, t.message, t.date, r.tid, r.admin, r.message, r.date FROM tbltickets t, tblticketreplies r WHERE t.id = r.tid AND t.date BETWEEN '2017-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-14 00:00:00' AND r.date > DATE_ADD(t.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY t.date
```

[image]

As you can see, what this code only did was first skip any ticket that doesn't have a reply that goes past that 1 day mark of the ticket DATE itself, but any ticket that is left it just skips the first message replies until it finds a message reply that is more than 1 day old from the ticket date

Ticket date: 10.sept
Ticket has 5.replies and all of them are same day except 1.

Result shows T.message and T.date then just that R.message and R.date skipping the first 4.

My Goal is to eliminate entirely tickets from the results where r.date is more than 1 day older than t.date but it has to be the first r.date the first reply as seen in screen 1 before the grouping by t.date.

I hope I am coming across like a sane person.

Comment: No pictures, thanks. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: No pictures? there are 3 pictures, am i not allowed to post pictures?

Comment: Pictures are nasty. You're allowed to post them, but they're hard to read and hard to work with.

Comment: Okay, what do you suggest so I can show this example? hmm

Comment: I can't just cut them and zoom them in? you can click on them to get the full resolution to understand them. Why is it that asking a question here usually ends with something like this, is my query this difficult to understand?

Comment: You can show the text of your result sets, indented four characters.  This is all about getting answers. Many Stack Overflow participants don't have the patience to try to read images.

Comment: You mean don't use pictures but show the output text? you mean run this via cli and post the text output?

Comment: "I am aware I can do GROUP BY t.date and that limits it showing just.. Which looks good " " `SELECT t.id, t.title, t.message, t.date, r.tid, r.admin, r.message, r.date... GROUP BY t.date`... it doesn't look good in fact you get random (read unrelated) data for each column used in the SELECT clause that isn't in the GROUP BY clause....https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: I get what you mean @RaymondNijland the Group By is just by "LUCK" taking exactly what I need for the second message, it's not good it's just pure luck that Its returning the exact result I need according to the document you just linked.. for my purposes its actually working but I can see what you mean.

Comment: I suggest reading.

Comment: I am reading what Raymond posted, it makes sense, I may actually end up having to look at this again, I didn't know that GROUP BY was just by some weird coincidence giving me the results that I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things. First, you're using the old join syntax. It has a retro, 1980s, feel to it.  Do this.

```
   FROM tbltickets t
   JOIN tblticketreplies r  ON t.id = r.tid
```

Second, your date filter is incorrect. (Using `BETWEEN` in date filters is almost never correct because it messes up the range end condition.) It gets items at midnight on `'2017-09-14 00:00:00'` but not after. If you want everything on 13-Sep and nothing on 14-Sep use ths.

```
     AND t.date >= '2017-09-01 00:00:00' 
     AND t.date <  '2017-09-14 00:00:00'
```

Making those fixes puts you in a position to solve your problem.

Next you need to create a subquery to identify just the "first"  reply for each ticket  That looks like this

```
           SELECT MIN(r.id) id, r.tid
             FROM tbltickets t
             JOIN tblticketreplies r
                        ON t.id = r.tid
                       AND r.date >= t.date + INTERVAL 24 HOUR
            GROUP BY r.tid
```

The `AND` part of the `ON` clause here excludes the replies older than 24 hours.
It gives either zero or one row per `tid`. (That's important!) It gives you the `id` value of the oldest row that is newer than 24 hours in your reply table.

You can test this query and make sure it does what you think it does.

Finally, use it in your main query

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, t.message, t.date,
       r.tid, r.admin, r.message reply, r.date reply_date 
  FROM tbltickets t
  JOIN tblticketreplies r ON t.id = r.tid
  JOIN (
               SELECT MIN(r.id) id, r.tid
                 FROM tbltickets t
                 JOIN tblticketreplies r
                            ON t.id = r.tid
                           AND r.date >= t.date + INTERVAL 24 HOUR
                GROUP BY r.tid
       ) latest ON r.id = latest.id AND t.id = latest.tid
 WHERE t.date >= '2017-09-01 00:00:00' 
   AND t.date <  '2017-09-14 00:00:00'
```

The second `JOIN` eliminates all but the single eligible row from your result set.

If you need to show all tickets, even those lacking eligible replies, use `LEFT JOIN` in place of the two `JOIN` operations.

**Edit** The above wipes out the responses older than 24 hours. I guess I misunderstood the requirement. Sorry about that.  I still have trouble understanding the requirement.

If you want to show each ticket as long as it has no responses within 24 hours, you can do this.

1) figure out when the most recent response to each ticket was. This gives the `date` of the most recent response to each ticket.

```
               SELECT MAX(date) date, r.tid
                 FROM tbltickets t
                 JOIN tblticketreplies r
                            ON t.id = r.tid
                GROUP BY r.tid
```

2) join that subquery into your main query,

```
 SELECT t.id, t.title, t.message, t.date,
       r.tid, r.admin, r.message reply, r.date reply_date 
  FROM tbltickets t
  JOIN tblticketreplies r ON t.id = r.tid
  JOIN (
               SELECT MIN(r.id) id, r.tid
                 FROM tbltickets t
                 JOIN tblticketreplies r
                            ON t.id = r.tid
                           AND r.date >= t.date + INTERVAL 24 HOUR
                GROUP BY r.tid
       ) latest ON r.id = latest.id AND t.id = latest.tid
  JOIN (
               SELECT MAX(date) date, r.tid
                 FROM tbltickets t
                 JOIN tblticketreplies r
                            ON t.id = r.tid
                GROUP BY r.tid
       ) recent ON t.id = recent.tid
 WHERE t.date >= '2017-09-01 00:00:00' 
   AND t.date <  '2017-09-14 00:00:00'
   AND t.date < recent.date + INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

That should throw out the tickets with the most recent response newer than 24 hours.  The overall trick is to use `GROUP BY` subqueries to figure out aggregated things you need like most recent dates and least recent ids, then use them.

I wish I understood your requirement better.

Comment: I didn't debug this stuff. It is presented so you can learn to use it, not so you can copy and paste it into your program without understanding it. Just sayin'

Comment: I understand, this works pretty similar to what I had already, what happened when i submitted this to check, although this looks more pro than what I did, it still returns the second r.message with +24 hours even though there is in fact responses in that ticket before those 24 hours. I need to eliminate any ticket which have ticket response less thatn 24 hours from the t.date, not just show response that are 24 hours old. This is to see any ticket in our database where our staff did not answer the first 24 hours to find who is at fault.

Comment: Customer submits ticket: Hey there ( 00:00 at 12.09.2017 )
First response from staff: Yo ( 00:00 at 14.09.2017 )

I need to find these, while anything like

Customer submits ticket: Hey there (00:00 at 12.09.2017)
Staff response: Ill take a look (00:05 at 12.09.2017)

While any tickets like this gets removed from the equation.

Comment: I just want to say your version is correct one I didn't mean it did the same as mine, just that mine coincidentally returns the right while yours does it by design. The only portion I am now stuck on is that when yours adds +24 hour interval, you still display ALL tickets between these dates just skip the first comments. It needs to skip tickets where there is first result comment under 24 hours :)

Comment: I think Ill use PHP to do the difference, this should be enough Ill accept this answer because it taught me alot :)